# How to avoid the crash when I scroll the tableview

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that when I scroll the table view then the application is crashing. So please tell me how to avoid the crashing when I scroll the table view.

Comment: Please post some code how you have implemented your UIScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

There may be couple of reasons for it.

1. You are accessing objects beyond the index of data(mostly array) you
   are providing.
2. You have over released objects contained in array ,Yo
   hence deallocated and causing a crash.
3. You have multiple arrays as sources(like sub arrays) and the you are actullay refering an out of bound index. (Same situation as one)
4. You are not returning a cell(nil) on tableview:cellforIndexpath: method. which is a must for tableview. Please check the cell object while debigging.

Answer (score 0):

Check Number of rows in section, may be this reason to crash the app when unbalanced rows in section